# Google Sheets - how to display the duplicated line with the best result

Tags: google-sheets

My students can redo as many times as they want a form with google forms but I want to save the best of their attempts in google sheet. How can I do it?

my data

[image: 1]

As you see in the hyperlink, jpbolle@hotmail.com appears twice: is it possible to conserve only the line with the best result (line 11)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A, $A1)>1
```

[image]

but it looks like your sheet is not english locale so try:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A; $A1)>1
```

---

### update:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A:B; 2; 0); 9^9; 2; 1; 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But what you propose is conditional formatting. Interesting but what I would like to do is to keep only the best line and... automatically. Because the test concerns hundreds of students